# SQL - Finding the AVG, MIN, MAX and SUM with ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

The task I have been given requires me to find the average, minimum, maximum and total cost of visits made by Tiddles the cat 'P0001' and vet Trevor McCafferty 'VO4'. This will be drawn from two tables, pet and visit.

Pet table structure:

```
pet_id, Name, Type, Breed, Gender, Born, owner_id, Notes
```

Visit table structure:

```
visit_id, pet_id, vet_id, Visit_Date, Basic_Cost, Symptom, Treatment
```

Below is the command I have created so far but I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly which is why I need help.

```
SELECT Name, Type, AVG(Basic_Cost), MIN(Basic_Cost), MAX(Basic_Cost), SUM(Basic_Cost)
FROM visit, pet
WHERE pet_id = 'P0001' AND vet_id = 'V04';
```

Any questions just ask and any help is appreciated as I'm stumped.

Comment: I'd imagine that the error message you get tells you very much what to do.  What is the symptom/error message?

Comment: You need to add GROUP BY Name, Type

Comment: Access says there is a syntax error in the JOIN operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FIRST(pet.Name) AS PetName,
    FIRST(pet.Type) AS PetType,
    AVG(Basic_Cost) AS AverageCost,
    MIN(Basic_Cost) AS MinCost,
    MAX(Basic_Cost) AS maxCost,
    SUM(Basic_Cost) AS TotalCost
FROM visit
    INNER JOIN pet ON visit.pet_id = pet.pet_id 
WHERE visit.pet_id = 'P0001'
    AND visit.vet_id = 'V04'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT pet.Name, pet.Type, AVG(Basic_Cost), MIN(Basic_Cost), MAX(Basic_Cost), SUM(Basic_Cost)
FROM visit, pet 
where visit.pet_id = pet.pet_id 
 and visit.pet_id = 'P0001' 
 and visit.vet_id = 'V04'
GROUP BY pet.Name, pet.Type;
```

Also you probably have to join visit and pet tables

Comment: I've added the GROUP BY but I now get the error 'the specified field pet_id could refer to more than one table in the FROM clause in your SQL statement. But which table should I link to?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that but I get back JOIN expression not supported.

Comment: @DAN212: I removed the INNER JOIN

Comment: It works but only the column headings are created. There is no data displayed.

Comment: @DAN212: Maybe `P0001` never visited `V04` ? Publishing your data would help.